# condensing JavaScript import localStorage

Tags: javascript

Below is the code that I came up with to import the values of a key in `localStorage` and supply each value the key holds into a `function`. Being that I'm very new to JavaScript, I was wondering if there's a better way to do what I did below and still provide the same outcome ?

**Code :**

```
function importStorage() {
    for (let i = 0; i < localStorage.length; i++) {
        const key = localStorage.key(i);             // This references the key
        const values = localStorage.getItem(key)     // This pulls the values associated
        const newValues = values.slice(2, -2)        // This removes this ( and this ) 
        const finalValues = newValues.split("', '")  // This then splits the string
        newBill(finalValues[0], finalValues[1], finalValues[2])
    }
}
```

Is there a better way to achieve it ?

Comment: why are you storing the value with `(` and `)` if it's not needed when you read it? a better way to store "complex" values may be using JSON.stringify and JSON.parse

Comment: It looks like you have lots of different LS items. Why not have an object (key/value pairs) that you can stringify and save that to LS. Then you can just load that in (once) and then iterate over those pairs rather than accessing LS multiple times. If you add an example of the strings you're storing to your question we might be able to help better.

Comment: I'm having JavaScript create a box in the browser window. The elements that it's storing are the data the function references to build it. I'm not entirely sure as to everything that JavaScript can do or what I should be doing to store and pull it, but the code at the end of the box creator function is as follows: `localStorage.setItem('${nameId}', '('${newItemName}', '${newItemAmount}', '${newItemFreq}')')` NOTE: I removed the ` marks present so as to not mess with the `code` notation

Comment: Could I have just put it in like this?  `localStorage.setItem('${nameId}', ${newItemName},${newItemAmount},${newItemFreq}')`?